# Is it possible to use "impdb" on Oracle 11g express on virtualbox?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, virtualbox

I need to use Oracle for development purpose on my OSX machine so I downloaded an **Oracle 11g Express virtualbox** which runs on Linux. Further, I do want to import a database dump file which was exported by "expdb" to this environment but I found that "impdb" tool is not a part of the Oracle 11g express virtualbox.

I have searched through many articles and documentations but it seems like "impdb" is shipped with the full installation of Oracle, not the express one (correct me if I'm wrong). Thus, **I wonder if is there any way I can use "impdb" to import my database dump file to this Oracle 11g express environment?**

Answer (score 1):

Datapump is available in XE:

Note! Look for expdp and impdp

```
§ WORKSTATION1 {C:\o\a\o\p\1\s\bin} dir *dp.exe


    Directory: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        27.08.2011     10:58     126976 expdp.exe
-a---        27.08.2011     10:58     131072 impdp.exe
```

Comment: Oops, my fault. I have just found `expdp` binary in the installation path (as referred to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL125). The binary is found at `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin`. So I have run an environment updater script in this dir and now I can invoke it.